# How do the laser pods (mines) work?

Tags: eufloria

I'm not sure to understand how the laser pods work, especially their culture/farming system.  It looks like you can only have one laser pod per defense tree you own at a time: once the laser pod has been produced, the defense tree it came from won't be able to grow a new seed into a new laser pod until the first one you produced get destroyed.

Also: how are the final laser pod's specs (energy/fight/speed) determined?  Is it some sort of average between 1/ the asteroid where the seed comes from and 2/ the asteroid where the defense tree host is situated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got that right on the way they grow:

Laser mines (not pods) can grow only on defense trees and only one mine per tree can be alive at any given time. That means, if a mine gets destroyed, eventually a new one will grow on the tree from which the old one originated.

The stats of a mine are determined solely by the asteroid on which they grow. The stats of the seedlings or even the flowers that made the tree are not relevant.

I can confirm those information from my own experience playing the game, but it is also discussed and explained in [this forum thread](http://www.euflorium.com/index.php?topic=513.0).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer !  Are you sure about the "mine" term ?  In the android version, I'm almost sure it's called "laser *pods*" :o

Comment: I'm 100% sure that they are called "mines" on the PC version. Have a look at the Steam achievements, they also refer to it as mine (http://steamcommunity.com/stats/Eufloria/achievements/). But maybe they changed it for Android, dunno.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to [Sentry's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94920/how-do-the-laser-pods-work/94938#94938), a defense tree only produces laser mines/pods if it has a flower added to it. So if the flower is lost, the tree won't produce laser pods.

I frequently use my mines to destroy enemies' flowers on enhanced Dyson or Defense Trees in asteroids with a few number of seeds.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufloria#Gameplay

Comment: Is it possible to destroy a flower already attached to a tree?

Comment: You can and you **must**

Comment: My seedlings ignore flowers. Are they destroyed only by mines?

Comment: Yes they are only destroyed by mines :/ .. I usually take 3 or 4 to make sure that mines don't get killed by defense trees